NIntegrate over a 2D Region
I am using Mathematica's ability to integrate over regions to find the mean aerodynamic cord of a wing planform. As an example, here is a simple wing, and its bounds.
points = {{0, 0}, {3, 300}, {120, 310}, {200, 0}}
wing = Polygon[points]
{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = RegionBounds[wing]
I can use the normal Integrate to find its area A. But the mean aerodynamic cord is:
$c_m=\frac{1}{A} \int_{R}^{ } c^2(y) \,dy$
where R is the region, and c(y) is the cord at any y. In the past, I did this by defining c(y) as:
c[R_,y_]:=ArcLength[RegionIntersection[R, InfiniteLine[{0, y}, {1, 0}]]]
and doing the integral like this:
cm = 1/A NIntegrate[c[wing, y]^2, {y, ymin, ymax}]
This has always worked, until I upgraded to Mathematica 14. Now it says the integrand is Undefined. Which is odd, because you can still plot:
Plot[c[wing, y]^2, {y, ymin, ymax}]
and it works.

$Version

(* "14.0.0 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (December 13, 2023)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

points = {{0, 0}, {3, 300}, {120, 310}, {200, 0}};

wing = Polygon[points];

A = Area[wing]

(* 48535 *)

A === Integrate[1, {x, y} ∈ wing]

(* True *)

{{xmin, xmax}, {ymin, ymax}} = RegionBounds[wing];

c[R_, y_] := ArcLength[RegionIntersection[R, InfiniteLine[{0, y}, {1, 0}]]]

Note that c cannot evaluate with symbolic arguments.
c[r, y]

(* ArcLength::reg: RegionIntersection[r,InfiniteLine[{0,y},{1,0}]] is not a correctly specified region.

ArcLength[RegionIntersection[r, InfiniteLine[{0, y}, {1, 0}]]] *)

Consequently, restrict it to non-symbolic arguments
Clear[c];
c[R_?RegionQ, y_?NumericQ] := ArcLength[
  RegionIntersection[R, InfiniteLine[{0, y}, {1, 0}]]]

cm = 1/A  NIntegrate[c[wing, y]^2, {y, ymin, ymax}]

(* 162.135 *)

